# Loading a static image as an openlayers map layer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, openlayers-3

I am trying to load an image into my openlayers canvas with the ultimate goal of loading a png file of our map legend as a layer on top of our map. I've been able to float the legend above the map with using `div` tags, but we need the legend to be captured within the canvas so that it can be saved by the user to a png file with the `canvas.toBlob()` functon.

I am not getting any errors that I can find, but my image is not appearing on top of my map.

my Javascript:

```
var pixelProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'pixel',
    units: 'pixels',
    extent: [0, 0, 800, 600]
})


var mapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
        url: 'http://184.185.140.81/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    }),
    opacity: 0.3,
    isBaseLayer: false
});

var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        //url: 'http://184.185.140.81/Futura_sample.PNG'
        url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png',
        imageSize: [800, 600],
        projection: pixelProjection,
        imageExtent: pixelProjection.getExtent()
    })
})

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        mapLayer,
        imageLayer
    ],
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.ScaleLine()
    ]),
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([4.666389, 50.009167], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 4,
        minZoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 20,
    })
});


$('#exportMap').on('click', function() {
    console.log('click');
    canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
        window.saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<div id="exportMapDiv">

   <input type="button" id="exportMap" value="download map">

</div>
```

This code is just trying to test the functionality with a sample png from wikipedia as I don't have our legend prepared yet. The commented `url:` is another sample image I have saved to `/var/www/html/Futura_sample.PNG`

What is it I am doing wrong?

Edit: solved. I need to fix the projection of my image. It was rendering and projecting the image fine, but somewhere in another galaxy so to speak.

Comment: Hope it help you `map.getLayers().push(imageLayer)`

Comment: Or maybe the problem is in your image projection